# Can windows-activated laptop can be detected when it's on through ActiveDirectory or some other way?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-activation

I know it's a long shot, but since I'm not knowledgeable enough in this matter, I'd like to hear from experts.
I'd like to know when my brother's laptop is on. I don't have access to it and I don't want to break into it or something like that. He added his laptop to my company's domain so to activate his windows. Is there a way to know if it's on through ActiveDirectory or other tool?

Comment: On the Server, open Task Manager and the open the users Tab.  The user will show up there.

Comment: Even if he's not connected to my network anymore?

Comment: If he is not on your network, he cannot be detected as an active user.

Comment: What kind of account you have that allowed him to activate Windows? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc - Author likely provided a VLK.  What the author doesn’t or likely didn’t take into account is the need for that machine to checkin once every 180 days otherwise it becomes deactivated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a bog-standard DHCP environment with AD-integrated DNS and DHCP services, then just `ping computername.domain.name` should do the trick.

If his firewall is set to not allow ICMP echo-* (i.e. no ping), just try `nc computername.domain.name 445` and see if it times out, succeeds or is rejected.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that his user was deactivated in AD and he's not connected to my network anymore. But, I know for sure that the windows on his laptop is still activated. I've checked that on his laptop. So, is this still possible in this case?

Comment: If he is not connected to your netweork, then the only thing you can't detect anything. Depending on your WPA details, his Windows activation might end after some time though